# How to make a Div's height change slower

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I want to make a Div appear by scrolling down on a button click slowly from the top of the page. But when I do it with what I have now, it just appears very fast and does not really slide down. What am I doing wrong?

```
function showstuff(inquiryForm){
   document.getElementById(inquiryForm).style.visibility="visible";
    for (var i=0;i<300;i++)
    {
        document.getElementById(inquiryForm).style.height= i + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: you need use setTimeout to delay each px increase

Answer (score 1):

You are looping 300 items and you try to find the element with **getELementById** and then trying to style the selected item

I think that makes the process really slow and laggy.

Comment: var t=setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById(inquiryForm).style.height= i + "px";
},3000)

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is an example that should help you understand the event loop,
```

and the use of setTimeout.

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:10px;height:50px;background:#f00;"></div>

<button class="btn" onclick="start();">Start</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="stop();">Stop</button> 
<button class="btn" onclick="reset();">Reset<button>

var timeout;

function start() {
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    var size = 10;

    var func = function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(func, 0);
        div.style.width = size + "px";
        if (size++ == 600) stop();
    }

    func();  // starts the process
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(timeout);
}

function reset() {
    var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    div.style.width = "10px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this sort of thing is often handled using jquery, as it includes various animation functions, including a convenient short form that would be useful here:

once you've included the jquery library, you can use a function like this:

```
$(inquiryForm).slideDown( 500 );
```

where the argument is duration of the effect in ms

like so:

```
function showstuff(inquiryForm){
    $(inquiryForm).slideDown( 500 );
}
```

Comment: I do already have jquery on the page, what would I replace with this?

Comment: you can also bind an event to the button directly with jquery, like so: `$('#myButton').on('click', function () { $('#myFormContainer').slideDown( 500 ); } )`  where #myButton is the selector for the button, and #myFormContainer is the selector for the div you want to show